# form post to rest api

Tags: php, html, rest, curl

i have been searching all the web and didnt know where to start , 
 created an html web form and when posting the form , i need to send the value to the rest api

my html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Create Event</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="view.css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="view.js"></script>
</head>



<body id="main_body" >

    <img id="top" src="top.png" alt="">
    <div id="form_container">
        <h1><a>Create Event</a></h1>
        <form id="form_4068" class="appnitro"  method="POST" action="theSiteite.php">
                    <div class="form_description">
            <h2>Create Event</h2>
        </div>                      
            <ul >

            <li id="li_2" >
        <label class="description" for="Title">Title </label>
        <div>
            <input id="Title" name="Title" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_5" >
        <label class="description" for="element_5">User </label>
        <div>
        <select class="element select medium" id="element_5" name="element_5"> 
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                    <option value="1" >option1</option>
                    <option value="2" >option2</option>
                    <option value="3" >option3</option>
        </select>
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_1" >
        <label class="description" for="element_1">Application ID </label>
        <div>
        <select class="element select medium" id="element_1"name="element_1"> 
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                <option value="1" >option1</option>
                <option value="2" >option2</option>
                <option value="3" >option3</option>

        </select>
        </div> 
        </li>
        <li id="li_3" >
        <label class="description" for="element_3">Change Log </label>
        <div>
            <textarea id="element_3" name="element_3" class="element textarea small"></textarea> 
        </div> 
        </li>
        <li id="li_4" >
        <label class="description" for="element_4">Description </label>
        <div>
            <textarea id="element_4" name="element_4" class="element textarea small"></textarea> 
        </div> 
        </li>

                    <li class="buttons">
                <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="4068" />

                <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </li>
            </ul>
        </form> 
    </div>
    <img id="bottom" src="bottom.png" alt="">




    <script type="text/javascript">
    //empty
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the request example provided by the restApi holder

```
curl -X POST 'https://api.newrelic.com/v2/applications/{application_id}/deployments.json' \
     -H 'X-Api-Key:{123456789}' -i \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -d \
'{
  "deployment": {
    "Title": "string",
    "changelog": "string",
    "description": "string",
    "user": "string"
  }
}'
```

and this is the JSON RESPONSE STRUCTURE provided :

```
{
  "deployment": {
    "Application id": "integer",
    "Title": "string",
    "changelog": "string",
    "description": "string",
    "user": "string",
    "timestamp": "datetime",
    "links": {
      "application": "integer"
    }
  }
}
```

i cant understand how to use the CURL functions neither the syntax. i tried with php but unsuccessful.

Comment: if you are using chrome, i suggest you to checkout Postman.

Comment: Looks like you need to sign up for an application id. Once you get the application id, replace the value in  the link. Remember to remove the curly brackets as well.

Comment: cURL is the way to do it, so you've answered your own question. If you're posting here hoping for someone to provide the code for you, you're in the wrong spot. Try hiring someone off of fiverr, or freelancer or something if you don't know how to write the code yourself.

Comment: You could always use AJAX

Answer (score 2):

I understand your situation because I faced a similar issue when I was new to web development.

You shouldn't post data from a form directly to an API if you're expecting a response. Forms weren't built for dealing with responses.

Here's what you should do (using simple PHP tools):

1. Set your form `action` to a script you'll create, say, `handler.php`
2. In `handler.php`, use curl to send the data to the server and obtain a response.
3. After obtaining the response, process it however you wish (maybe save to a database), then redirect to a page of your choice by using `header("Location: <address>");`

Check out these links if you have trouble

- [working with curl](http://www.techflirt.com/php/php-curl/index.html)
- [sending and receiving requests](https://lornajane.net/posts/2008/using-curl-and-php-to-talk-to-a-rest-service)

All the best!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to sign up for an application id. Once you get the application id, replace the value in the link. Remember to remove the curly brackets as well.

After this paste the curl request part in your question/documentation reference into a terminal/command prompt. It should give you the response.

Also in the form tag, action can be replaced with the final link you obtain. 
But I recommend using an [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) call instead.